# Update D3 chart dynamically

Tags: d3.js

The idea is to have a d3 vertical bar-chart that will be given live data.
I simulate the live data with a setInterval function that updates the the values of the elements in my dataset:

```
var updateData = function(){
    a = parseInt(Math.random() * 100),
    b = parseInt(Math.random() * 100),
    c = parseInt(Math.random() * 100),
    d = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    dataset = [a, b, c, d];
    console.log(dataset);
};

// simullate live data input
var update = setInterval(updateData, 1000);
```

I want to update the chart every 2 seconds.
For that I need a update function that gets the new dataset and then animates a transition to show the new results. 
Like that:

```
var updateVis = function(){
   ..........
};

var updateLoop = setInterval(drawVis,2000);
```

I don't want to simply remove the chart and draw again. I want to animate the transition between the new and old bar height for each bar.

Checkout the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adai183/7un651z2/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your not changing the number of bars, this can be as simple as:

```
var updateVis = function(){
   svg.selectAll(".input")
    .data(dataset)
    .transition()
    .attr("y",  function(d) {
            return y(d);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return h - y(d);
    });
};
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7un651z2/11/).

But your next question becomes, what if I need a different number of bars?  This is where you need to handle enter, update, exit a little better.  You you can write one function for initial draw or updating.

```
function drawVis(){

 // update selection
 var uSel = svg.selectAll(".input")
        .data(dataset);

 // those exiting
 uSel.exit().remove();

 // new bars
 uSel
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "input")
        .attr("fill", "rgb(250, 128, 114)");

 // update all
 uSel
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length) + 2.5/100 * w;
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", y(0))
        .transition().duration(750).ease("linear")
        .attr("y",  function(d) {
            return y(d);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return h - y(d);
});

}
```

New [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7un651z2/13/).

Answer (score 1):

That's the way to go. 
Just think what you've done to get the initial chart:
1) Get data
2) Bind it to element (`.enter()`)
3) Set element attributes to be function of the data.

Well, you do this again:
In the function `updateData` you get a new `dataset` that's the first step.
Then, rebind it:

```
d3.selectAll("rect").data(dataset);
```

And finally update the attributes:

```
d3.selectAll("rect").attr("y",  function(d) {
        return y(d);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h - y(d);
    });
```

(Want transitions? Go for it. It is easy to add in your code but you better read [this tuto](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.cscrs849y) if you want to deeply understand it)

[Check it on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7jhs6dd/1/)