# d3js how to make a graph live update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a javascript code with the variable `dataSet` which is basically a list that from time to time I push elements ( integers ) to this list.

Now, what I want to do is to plot it once the dataSet has new elements,
I found this nice graph:

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c506ac45617cf9ed39337f99f8511218

but it has no ability update feature.
I tried very hard to find some sufficient examples on the internet but they all included extracting data from back-end and combination of them.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) illustrating how the data gets updated, and how the chart is created.

Comment: The new "Learn d3" tutorials should help, especially parts 6, 7 and 8: https://observablehq.com/collection/@d3/learn-d3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update D3 chart dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320575/update-d3-chart-dynamically)